# HLSL Texture sample fine when directly returned, invalid if any operation is applied

Tags: shader, hlsl, directx-9, pixel-shader

I am new to shaders and HLSL, I hope I'm not doing anything seriously incorrect. I am trying to blend two textures in HLSL. I've got both of my textures and samplers set up:

```
Texture2D<float4> First : register(t0);
Texture2D<float4> Second : register(t1);
uniform sampler FirstSampler : register(s0);
uniform sampler SecondSampler : register(s1);
```

In my pixel shader, I am sampling my textures:

```
float4 firstSample = First.Sample(FirstSampler, coords);
float4 secondSample = Second.Sample(SecondSampler, coords);
```

Now, at this point, if I directly return `firstSample` or `secondSample`, I get correct results. However, I'm trying to interpolate between my textures. I tried:

```
float4 returnValue = lerp(firstSample, secondSample, 0.5);
```

But what I'm getting is an interpolation between pure black and my second texture. If I switch their places, I'm getting the same result. If I set the weight to be 0.0, I get pure black etc. meaning that there is something wrong about the `firstSample`. I've also tried to manually interpolate between them using pure math component-wise, instead of `lerp`, but it also yields the same result. Most weird thing is that, when I directly return my `firstSample` or return some value without interacting with the other sample (e.g. `return float4(firstSample.b, firstSample.g, firstSample.r, 1);` for channel swapping), I get a working result, but whenever I try to use my texture with any other sample, my texture sample becomes effectively invalid (black). What could be the reason? I am very new to shaders to it's probably something I'm doing obviously wrong, but I couldn't find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The results you are seeing may be due to a compiler bug.  Ensure that you are using a recent version of the HLSL compiler, either Version 46 from the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx), or Version 43 from the [June 2010 DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812).

Comment: i am using (and have to use) directx toolkit compiler that ships with sharpdx, so i can't 'update to latest' compiler. i have the latest version of that compiler though, which was updated pretty recently.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu Can you post the full shader code along with the compilation options?

Comment: i've currently modified the original code when i posted the question a lot, and trying to get rid of other problems. that specific problem seemed to go away now, but i just can't be sure that it won't come back with a change in a simple line. i'll try to, however, investigate the issue down to the specific code block and when i'm done with that i'll post that.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I'm not very hopeful here, but... Did you ever figure this out? I'm currently experiencing this bug as well.

Comment: @JSQuareD Yes, I did figure it out eventually back then. But I honestly don't remember how. It's been about two years and I don't even develop for WP anymore :( If I recall correctly it was something related to the types of the parameters, but I could be making up, I really don't remember.